# What happens when we close the script two times?

Tags: javascript

This might be a silly question but i want to clarify this. what happens when we close a javascript two times.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("hello");
</script>
</script>
```

i did this but am not getting any error.its like we closed the script so there wont be any execution so no error will trigger i believe. will this create trouble under any situation?

why am asking this is i would like to insert a `</script>` at the end of a plugin where user submits their script. So that i don't have to go for extra coding on validation if this works fine without creating any trouble

Comment: I think the browser omits it. It's not valid XHTML though.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: It is extra invalid markup, why would you have it anyway ?

Comment: i don't have to go for validation if this works fine without creating any trouble

Comment: What if the user ends their script with a backslash?

Comment: Your project does not become more secure by putting in a closing script tag, if that's what you think.

Comment: e.g. my script ends with `<!-- ` see what happens

Comment: @DanFromGermany So you are saying validation is the only way there otherwise this way is not recomended

Comment: Depending on the source of the script you'd like to include, the answer is yes in most cases. If you'd describe your problem and circumstances a little closer one could suggest alternatives as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The browser will treat this as an extra, unexpected end tag. It doesn't matter that it's `</script>`, it could also be `</link>` or anything else allowed in the same context.

Most browers will silently ignore such extra tags unless you enable strict / XML mode. For strict mode, you should get errors in the console.

To properly wrap plugins supplied by the user, I suggest this strategy:

- Always wrap them in your own tags (so you can be sure the structure is always correct).
- Check the string that you put between the two tags for `<script`, `<script>` and `</script>` and report an error if you find any of them.

The idea here is that users should never use script tags in their code and that you put them where they belong.

Comment: `document.write("<" + "script" + ">")`

Comment: (and don't even think you'd be able to ban `document.write`)

Comment: I know about `document.write`. The point above is to prevent accidental usage of `<script>` tags that shouldn't be there. If an attacker wants to break the rules, then you need to analyze the attack and find a solution. There is no generic always-safe solution.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers will just remove/ignore an extra  tag.  I can't see that it's would cause any problems, but it is quite an ugly way to do it.  I have no better suggestion currently though.

Answer (score 0):

nothing. the browser ignores it but it will obviously not pass standards.

as far as i know, if the browser comes across an opening `<script>` tag, it assumes everything until the closing `</script>` tag is script. so starting with a `</script>` will have no effect but to cause an 'unexpected` exception.

Comment: will it cause any problem?

Answer (score 0):

The effect may change depending on the browser, but in teory all ignore the second tag.

Answer (score 0):

> XHTML rules are much stricter than those of HTML. When special XML
>   characters (such as & and <) are used in scripts in XHTML files, they
>   cause errors. The simplest workaround is to use external script files.
>   However, if you simply must write inline scripts, then you will need
>   to include CDATA (character data) sections in your file. Within CDATA
>   sections the special XML characters can be used freely. The following
>   example uses a CDATA section that is compatible with both XHTML and
>   HTML syntax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  alert((1 < 2) && (3 > 2));
//]]>
</script>
```

***Also it is not a correct practice and if the script is inline than it will break W3C compliance.***

Answer (score 0):

To answer your direct question: Nothing would happen, it's just invalid (x)HTML which the browser ignores.

To answer your indirect question, turned out in the comments:

> @DanFromGermany So you are saying validation is the only way there otherwise this way is not recomended

Validation of external resources is always critical.

For example, simply reading external scripts into `<script></script>` tags, tells the browser "this is no external content" and hereby grants more access, for example, read your cookies and set cookies originating from **your domain** *(external content....your domain)*.

Including external JS via `<script src="...">`, from a different host/domain, tells the browser *"this is a 3rd party script, don't allow it as much as internal scripts."* It is therefore not allowed to read or set your cookies and stuff.

Why putting in `</script>` does not help:

An attacker is **easily** able to screw your whole website and let it easily disappear.

See the following:

```
<script>
<!-- external script start -->

</script>
</head>
<body>

Attackers website start


<div style="display:hidden;">

everything below disappears

<!--

<!-- external script end -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- your website start !-->
```

Still if you prevent this, an attacker can always use `document.write();` to insert HTML into your Website.

Probably the best way is to executed the given JS through an iframe, from a blank page and an independent (sub)domain.

Putting things into database, or save ones JS and let it execute by a different user needs additional validation.

Comment: my plugin circumstances is user will just going to see preview of what they are giving in script section. Example-like jsfiddle kind of thing.

Comment: jsfiddles do get executed in a blankpage, but most important, under an independent domain (from jsfiddle.net to http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/) so the executed script is executed as 3rd party script.